# Meteor AutoForm stops proceeding submit

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I would like to create a form, using the autoform package for Meteor, for my `CAS_Entry` collection. The code can be seen below. I also added the defined hooks, of which unfortunately only `beginSubmit` and `before` are executed and no entry is added to the collection. Using Meteor shell, the insert works like a charm.

I am grateful for any hint.

addCasEntry.html, Template for displaying the form:

```
{{#autoForm collection="CAS_Entry" type="insert" id="addCasEntryForm"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="type" options="allowed"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="description" rows="6" type="textarea"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="file" type="cfs-file" collection="Images"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="date" }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

addCasEntry.js, adding debugging hooks:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  addCasEntryForm: {
    before: {
      insert: function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      }
    },
    after: {
      insert: function(error, result) {
        console.log('Occured error: ' + error);
      }
    },
    beginSubmit: function() {
      console.log('begin submit');  
    },
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
      console.log("Insert succeeded");
      console.log('Result ' + result);
    },
    onError: function(formType, error) {
      console.log('Error!!!');
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});

SimpleSchema.debug = true;
```

/lib/collection/cas_entry.js:

```
CAS_Entry = new Mongo.Collection("cas_entries");

CAS_Entry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['reflection', 'evidence']
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  file: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  timeUploaded: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
      return new Date();
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
  }
}));

CAS_Entry.allow({
  'insert': function() {
    return true;
  },
  'update': function() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

And here is the console output:

[image: console output]

Comment: did you attach a schema to your form?

Comment: I attached a schema to the collection. Therefore, autoform should use this by default, as far as I know. This worked for the rest of my forms.

Comment: yes that's what i meant. so did yo utry the debug option to see if the schema may be filtering out some of your data?

Comment: `SimpleSchema.debug = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form won't be submitted because you are not returning or passing the document to `this.result();` inside your [**`before`**](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) hook.

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  addCasEntryForm: {
    // ...
    before: {
      insert: function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        return doc;
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks), you should use one of the following statements depending on your defined preconditions:

- Synchronous, submit: `return doc;`.
- Synchronous, cancel: `return false;`.
- Asynchronous, submit: `this.result(doc);`.
- Asynchronous, cancel: `this.result(false);`.

Comment: Ok, very dumb mistake, I have to admit. So it is a bug that appears when the programmer starts to study the code.